# Swift creating JSON data from AnyObject

Tags: json, swift

Unfortunately I didn't find anything useful for *writing* JSON data on the internet. I wanted to ask what I have to do to let a class become a 'valid JSON object' that can be converted to JSON using `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(<AnyObject>, options: .allZeros, error: nil)`. Does data have to be either a value like `String` or `NSNumber` or an object such as `Array<AnyObject>` or `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`, which are objects that can easily be represented in JSON or are there any other possibilities to convert a JSON object? Thanks for your answers

Comment: It's way out of my area-of-expertise but maybe something here will help you: https://medium.com/swift-programming/4-json-in-swift-144bf5f88ce4  They definitely talk about using a dict/array tree as the input object and I see the function you described being used there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSJSONSerialization Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html):

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> - The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
> - All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray,
>     NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

If you have other objects you have to manually convert them to one of these basic objects. So basically String and NSNumber. As far as I know there is no protocol that you can implement to turn your class into a JSONSerializable object.

In my opinion the best way to get your own objects into JSON is to create a method that returns a dictionary that only contains the allowed types. For the opposite way you can create a init that takes a dictionary.

Such an implementation would look like this:

```
class FancyObject {
    let color: UIColor
    let creationDate: NSDate
    let title: String

    init(title: String, color: UIColor) {
        self.color = color
        self.title = title
        self.creationDate = NSDate()
    }

    init(dictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let colorString = dictionary["color"] as String
        self.color = UIColor(rgbaString: colorString)!
        self.title = dictionary["title"] as String
        let dateString = dictionary["creationDate"] as String
        self.creationDate = posixDateFormatter().dateFromString(dateString)!
    }

    func jsonRepresentation() -> [String : AnyObject] {
        var json = [String : AnyObject]()
        json["color"] = self.color.rgbaString()
        json["title"] = self.title
        json["creationDate"] = posixDateFormatter().stringFromDate(self.creationDate)
        return json
    }
}
```

If you want to play around in the Playground here is the other stuff that is referenced:

```
extension UIColor {
    func rgbaString() -> String? {
        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0
        if self.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha) {
            return "\(red),\(green),\(blue),\(alpha)"
        }
        return nil
    }

    public convenience init?(rgbaString: String) {
        var red: Float = 0
        var green: Float = 0
        var blue: Float = 0
        var alpha: Float = 1

        let scanner = NSScanner(string: rgbaString)
        scanner.scanFloat(&red)
        scanner.scanString(",", intoString: nil)
        scanner.scanFloat(&green)
        scanner.scanString(",", intoString: nil)
        scanner.scanFloat(&blue)
        scanner.scanString(",", intoString: nil)
        scanner.scanFloat(&alpha)
        self.init(red: CGFloat(red), green: CGFloat(green), blue: CGFloat(blue), alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }
}

func posixDateFormatter() -> NSDateFormatter {
    let posixDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    posixDateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US_POSIX")
    posixDateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
    posixDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"
    return posixDateFormatter
}

let originalObject = FancyObject(title: "Object 1", color: UIColor.magentaColor())
let originalJSONDictionary = originalObject.jsonRepresentation()
var error: NSError?
let json = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(originalJSONDictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &error)
if json == nil {
    println("Can't create json \(error)")
}

/* JSON:
{
  "title" : "Object 1",
  "creationDate" : "2015-03-14T23:04:35Z",
  "color" : "1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0"
}
*/

let dictionaryFromJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json!, options: nil, error: &error) as? [String : AnyObject]
if dictionaryFromJSON == nil {
    println("Can't create dict \(error)")
}
let objectFromJSON = FancyObject(dictionary: dictionaryFromJSON!)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html) the definitive way is to call `isValidJSONObject:` or try:

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> - The top level object is an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.
> - All objects are instances of `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, or `NSNull`.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of `NSString`.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity.
>
> Other rules may apply. Calling `isValidJSONObject:` or attempting a
>   conversion are the definitive ways to tell if a given object can be
>   converted to JSON data.